# Neural network regression problem, integer output neuron constraint

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

The problem I'm solving is a regression problem using neural networks, and the "y" value covers a very large range (let's say y represents the number of people, ranging from 0 people to 10000 people), which makes it impossible to be interpreted as a classification problem.

The only difference between the problem I'm solving right now and the ordinary regression problem is that the output neuron should produce a strict integer, not decimal.

Is there any activation function that can handle this constraint?  Or what's the appropriate way to approach to model this constraint?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to approach this as a regression problem, mostly because you are interested in the order of your outputs. For example if there are 1000 people present and you predict 1005, it's a better prediction than 7005. If you were treating this as a classification problem, both of these would be interpreted as *missclassifications*.

The most practical way to approach your constraint is to **round** the output of your neural network, i.e. if it outputs 3456.78, round it up to 3457. You need to have a linear activation function to be able to use the NN for regression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to regress a contineous value, and apply a rounding afterwards.

Then, you are looking for a neural network that maps an input to a value y >=0.
There are many activation functions which you could use, for example linear and quadratic functions. According to the Universal Approximation Theorem, you should use non-linear activation functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.